# Define origin and length of the Strel function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to create the following structuring element (SE):

[g+ and g-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzK8d.png)

The underline bar represents the origin of the SE.

For example, if I want an SE of g+ and g- with length equal to 3, how could I do it through the MATLAB strel function?

References: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html#d123e281224

Comment: The origin is always in the middle, just create a matrix padded with zeros so that your origin is in the middle of the array. Something like `[0,0,1,1,1]`.

Comment: So g+ = [0,0,1,1,1] and g- = [1,1,1,0,0] ?